# How to find node voltage by VDR

Tags: circuit

how to determine the node voltage Vab using VDR.

[Circuit diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ugX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask questions like this on the electrical engineering Stack Exchange site here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

But anyway, since the resistors are all in series you can use the simple [series resistance formula](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_5.html) to find that the total series resistance is:

```
Rt = 2.5 + 1.5 + 0.6 + 0.9 + 0.5 = 6 Ohms
```

This means the current through the circuit is:

```
I = V/R = 0.36/6 = 0.06 A (60 mA)
```

The voltage across Vab is `Vab = Va - Vb` so:

```
Va = IR = 0.06 * 0.5 = 0.03 V (30 mV)
Vb = IR = 0.06 * (1.5 + 0.6 + 0.9 + 0.5) = 0.06 * 3.5 = 0.21 V (210 mV)
Vab = 0.21 - 0.03 = 0.18 V (180 mV)
```

This can be shortened to:

```
Vab = IR = 0.06 * (1.5 + 0.6 + 0.9) = 0.18 (180 mV)
```

To further your learning I would suggest learning about [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)